# Loading a specific row from database into a html table

Tags: php, html, mysql

As you can see I have developed a html/php page to create orders and I am having issues trying to load data from a table (MySQL) into that table I created in html. What I want is the user to digit an ID (identification) a secondary key like order number and then the whole row goes to my table. where he can edit, delete and save the row. So far i have the table and I was able to load the whole tabe in the html page.

HTML:

```
<p>What order number would you like to load?<input type="text" id="SKU" maxlength="10" size="10" placeholder="Search for SKU..." title="Type an SKU..."><button onclick="myCreateFunction()">LOAD</button></p>
<table id="itemsTable"> <tr> ID <th>Quantity</th> 
                                              <th>Item</th> 
                                            <th>SKU</th> 
                                            <th>Item Name</th> 
                                            <th>Item Price</th> 
                                            <th>Subtotal</th> 
                                            <th>Cartons Scanned</th> 
                                            <th>Individually Scanned</th> 
                                            <th>Current Inventory</th> 
                                            <th>Location Selected</th> 
                                            <th>Image</th> 
                                            <th>Edit</th>
                                    </tr> 
                        <tr>
                              
                        </tr> 
</table>
```

now the php:

```
<?php
//Step2
$query = "SELECT * FROM item_new WHERE SKU=input ";
mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$all_property = array();  //declare an array for saving property

//showing property
echo '<table id="itemsTable" class="data-table">
        <tr class="data-heading">';  //initialize table tag
while ($property = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {
    echo '<td>' . $property->name . '</td>';  //get field name for header
    array_push($all_property, $property->name);  //save those to array
}
echo '</tr>'; //end tr tag

//showing data selected by the user (input)
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($all_property as $item) {
        echo '<td>' . $row[$item] . '</td>'; //get items using property value
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
```

[database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNX28.jpg)

script

```
<script>
function myCreateFunction() {
  var input 
  input = document.getElementById("SKU");
  
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with http://datatables.net/?

Comment: From what I understand you need to study working with HTML form handling try this w3schools tutorial to get an idea https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: the title and the question body does not make sense do you want to load a specific row of data or you want to search sku data (which can return many records)?

Comment: @MarvinCollins I'd want to show up all rows where sku value matches the user input

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code block for you solution

there will be two ways to fetch data as you want one can be using AJAX which is bit of complex and another is using form.

```
<p>What order number would you like to load?</p>
<form type="post" action=''>
    <input type="text" name='input_field' id="SKU" maxlength="10" size="10" placeholder="Search for SKU..." title="Type an SKU...">
    <input type='submit' name='search'>
</form>
<table id="itemsTable">                 
    <tr> 
        <th>ID</th> 
        <th>Quantity</th> 
        <th>Item</th> 
        <th>SKU</th> 
        <th>Item Name</th> 
        <th>Item Price</th> 
        <th>Subtotal</th> 
        <th>Cartons Scanned</th> 
        <th>Individually Scanned</th> 
        <th>Current Inventory</th> 
        <th>Location Selected</th> 
        <th>Image</th> 
        <th>Edit</th>
    </tr> 

<?php

//Check if form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM item_new WHERE SKU='".$_POST['input_field']."'";
    mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $all_property = array(); 

    //showing property
    while ($property = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {
        array_push($all_property, $property->name);  //save those to array
    }

    //showing data selected by the user (input)
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($all_property as $item) {
            echo '<td>' . $row[$item] . '</td>'; //get items using property value
        }
        echo "<a href='myeditpage?id=".$_row['id']."' >Edit product</a>"
        echo '</tr>';
    }

}

?>
</table>
```

in upper example we first let the user to input the data using input and when user click on search it will submit the form to current URL.
after that we check if user submitted the form or not if submitted the we will fetch data and print on the table.